# Installing dlib on Windows 11 Python 3.10.7

Tags: python, pip, dlib, windows-11

I was trying ot install dlib on Windows 11 using Python version 3.10.7.

After running `pip install dlib` the following error occured:

```
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.1.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for dlib (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext

      ERROR: CMake must be installed to build dlib

      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
Failed to build dlib
ERROR: Could not build wheels for dlib, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I know there is a specific way to install dlib using cmake but I cant figure out how to download it as everywhere I've looked have given solutions for windows 10. If anyone has a solution or knows a way to download dlib with my specific requirment please let me know!

---

Comment: Windows 11 is the same as Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Download CMake from https://cmake.org/download/

After installing, add it to system path (Environmental Variables > Path > Click New and Add the Path There > Click OK to Save)

Try `pip install dlib` again.